# How to open lightning network channel to a selected node in Electrum?

Tags: lightning-network, electrum

Electrum (version 4.1.2) Open Channel dialog only contains a dropdown "Trampoline" with predefined entries. How a new channel can be opened to a specific node?

[image: Electrum Open Channel Dialog]

Answer (score 3):

Go into Tools -> Preferences -> Lightning and disable the setting "Use Trampoline Routing (disable gossip)". If you now try to open a new channel you will see that you can put the full node id there in a generic text field, and the drop down is gone.